# MongoDB - $geoNear with multiple matches in same document

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection that looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5783051796a90cd8098fc3e0"),
    "name" : "Org 1",
    "locations" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "loc 1",
            "_id" : ObjectId("57831ac2febcceaf173e81ab"),
            "address" : {
                "coordinates" : [ 
                    172.6034932, 
                    -43.5333797
                ]
            }
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "loc 2",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5783436dc57b8d6248c9c196"),
            "address" : {
                "coordinates" : [ 
                    172.6034977, 
                    -43.5335158
                ]
            }
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "loc 3",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5783439bc57b8d6248c9c197"),
            "address" : {
                "coordinates" : [ 
                    168.6626435, 
                    -45.0311622
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

There is a `2dsphere` index on `locations.address.coordinates`

I'm using `aggreagate` with `geonear` to query those documents:

```
db.organisations.aggregate([
    {
        $geoNear: {
            near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ 172.6036799 , -43.5335639 ] },
            distanceField: "dist.calculated",
            maxDistance: 5,
            includeLocs: "dist.location",
            num: 5,
            limit: 200,
            spherical: true
        }
    }
])
```

This aggregation works fine and I get all the documents with at least 1 location in the selected area.
The problem is that I would like to retrieve only the relevant locations when there is more than 1 match inside 1 document.

MongoDB is able to tell me which one is the closest with `includeLocs` option, but that's not enough as I would like all the details.

At least, if I had the distance for each location, I could filter it later on the aggregation pipe. With the `distanceField` option I can get the distance found for the whole document, but not for each matching location

To recap: **My goal is to find all documents with at least 1 matching location, and know which are the relevant locations among the locations array.**

Is there way to get it or am I asking too much to Mongo?

Answer (score 6):

Completely re-wrote answer given the clarification.

You are correct, [$geoNear](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) must be the first stage. The solution lies in using "$unwind" and "$redact" to compare the matching location document provided by geoNear to the corresponding array element.

Test data:

```
db.test.insert({ "locs" : [ 
{ "name" : "a", "address" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ 0, 0 ] } }, 
{ "name" : "b", "address" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ 1, 1 ] } }, 
{ "name" : "c", "address" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ 2, 2 ] } }
]})

db.test.insert({ "locs" : [ 
{ "name" : "h", "address" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ 1.01, 1.01 ] } }
]})

db.test.ensureIndex( { "locs.address" : "2dsphere" } )
```

Query:

```
db.test.aggregate([
{ "$geoNear" : { near : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ 1, 1 ] }, distanceField: "dist.calculated", maxDistance: 5000, includeLocs: "dist.location", num: 5, limit: 200, spherical: true } },
{ "$unwind" : "$locs" },
{ "$redact" : { 
  "$cond" : { 
    if : { "$eq" : [ { "$cmp" : [ "$locs.address", "$dist.location" ] }, 0 ] },
    then : "$$KEEP", 
    else : "$$PRUNE"
   } 
 } 
}
])
```

The geoNear stage will output the entire documents with a "dist" field showing the distance and matching location field:

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("5786fa0ddeb382a191a43122"), 
  "locs" : [ { "name" : "h", "address" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ 1.01, 1.01 ] } } ],
  "dist" : { 
    "calculated" : 0, 
    "location" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ 1, 1 ] }
  } 
}
```

We [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the "locs" array to allow for accessing individual array elements. The dist field is preserved.

The [$redact](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) field can then be used to remove any array elements where the address does not match the location returned by the $geoNear stage.

Results:

```
{ 
 "_id" : ObjectId("5786fa0ddeb382a191a43121"), 
 "locs" : { "name" : "b", "address" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ 1, 1 ] } }, 
 "dist" : { "calculated" : 0, "location" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ 1, 1 ] } } 
}
{ 
 "_id" : ObjectId("5786fa0ddeb382a191a43122"), 
 "locs" : { "name" : "h", "address" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ 1.01, 1.01 ] } }, 
 "dist" : { "calculated" : 1574.1651198970692, "location" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ 1.01, 1.01 ] } } 
}
```

On a broader note, you may want to consider adjusting the data model so only include a single geo-spatial point per document. The distance data provided by geoNear seems to only refer to a single document, so there may be issues in the future if you want to filter by multiple documents.

Comment: My question might not be perfectly clear, I've edited it. My goal is to find all documents with at least 1 matching location, and know which are the relevant locations among the locations array. Unfortunately, you're answer won't give me the details of which locations matched. BTW, $geoNear can only be used on first stage of a pipeline

Comment: @Tdy You are absolutely correct about geoNear. Re-wrote answer given your additional information.

Comment: Thanks for this very detailed answer! That works fine when you have only 1 matching location per document, or if you only want the closest. My issue was knowing the distance for each location and being able to get _all_ the matching locations. That's your point at the end of the anwser and you're right. I ended up refactoring my data model, storing the locations in their own collection and add a reference to it in my original document. I think MongoDB just can do what I want right now.
Your answer can help people dealing with $geoNear but it won't solve my issue. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Tdy I have the same problem did you find a solution? Or did you change your data model?

Comment: @Fogia Long time I didn't work on this project but as I remember, I ended up by changing a bit the data model. I didn't manage to do what I wanted in one query